# Can't get jQuery.noConflict to properly work

Tags: jquery

I'll start out with saying I have little to no javascript experience other than editing and looking up tutorials on scripts. I've been utilizing a small shout box script on my site for a while. Since the addition of new plugins and scripts I've found an issue.

The Shoutbox stores about 10-15 lines of text in a text file displaying them and updating ( ajax style ) as they go and deleting after 15. Simple little script.

Now the Shoutbox no longer loads up the text, just shows up blank. I've attempted to utilize the jQuery.noConflict(); option but to no avail. It DOES load the box but when hitting submit ( to post the data ) ( there is no SQL involved ) nothing happens. If I refresh though it will show in the box. SO I know it has to do with passing the data live.

Here is the script ( not to big )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    var files = 'application/widgets/nipunashoutbox/demos/jquery-shoutbox/';
    var lastTime = 0;

    function prepare(response) {
      var d = new Date();
      count++;
      d.setTime(response.time*1000);
      var mytime = d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes();
      var string = '<div class="shoutbox-list" id="list-'+count+'">'
          + '<span class="shoutbox-list-time">'+mytime+'</span>'
          + '<span class="shoutbox-list-nick">'+response.nickname+':</span>'
          + '<span class="shoutbox-list-message">'+response.message+'</span>'
          +'</div>';

      return string;
    }

    function success(response, status)  { 
      if(status == 'success') {
        lastTime = response.time;
        $('#daddy-shoutbox-response').html('<img src="'+files+'images/accept.png" />');
        $('#daddy-shoutbox-list').prepend(prepare(response));
        $('input[@name=message]').attr('value', '').focus();
        $('#list-'+count).fadeIn('slow');
        timeoutID = setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
      }
    }

    function validate(formData, jqForm, options) {
      for (var i=0; i < formData.length; i++) { 
          if (!formData[i].value) {
              alert('Please fill in all the fields'); 
              $('input[@name='+formData[i].name+']').css('background', 'red');
              return false; 
          } 
      } 
      $('#daddy-shoutbox-response').html('<img src="'+files+'images/loader.gif" />');
      clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    }

    function refresh() {
      $.getJSON(files+"daddy-shoutbox.php?action=view&time="+lastTime, function(json) {
        if(json.length) {
          for(i=0; i < json.length; i++) {
            $('#daddy-shoutbox-list').prepend(prepare(json[i]));
            $('#list-' + count).fadeIn('slow');
          }
          var j = i-1;
          lastTime = json[j].time;
        }
        //alert(lastTime);
      });
      timeoutID = setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
    }

    // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var options = { 
          dataType:       'json',
          beforeSubmit:   validate,
          success:        success
        }; 
        $('#daddy-shoutbox-form').ajaxForm(options);
        timeoutID = setTimeout(refresh, 100);
    });
```

What I've attempted at doing after checking out multiple websites ( including stackoverflow discussions) was add the snippet  noConflict.jQuery();   after the first script line.

Then slowly replacing each $ with jQuery and or a different variable after assigning it to jQuery. The closest I've gotten was where it would freeze on loading the update, that or it would launch a new page echoing:

```
{"response":"Good work","nickname":"myusername","message":".","time":1364101631}
```

Currently seeking help as I would love to have this working again. Hopefully I've been able to explain enough if not I apologize and please let me know what else I should include. Thank you for your time in reading this, and I appreciate any support.

**Edit**

My apologies I forgot to include the scripts being called in the header:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="application/widgets/nipunashoutbox/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="application/widgets/nipunashoutbox/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `jQuery.noConflict();` equal to a variable. From there you can replace it. Where ever your chat box is call you can do something like:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('jQuery is loaded'); // lets you know jQuery has loaded
}
```

So in your case:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    var count = 0;
    var files = 'application/widgets/nipunashoutbox/demos/jquery-shoutbox/';
    // omitting some code...
    function success(response, status)  { 
      if(status == 'success') {
            lastTime = response.time;
            j('#daddy-shoutbox-response').html('<img src="'+files+'images/accept.png" />');
            j('#daddy-shoutbox-list').prepend(prepare(response));
            j('input[@name=message]').attr('value', '').focus();
            j('#list-'+count).fadeIn('slow');
            timeoutID = setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
      }
    }

    // omitting more code...
</script>
```

You will need to replace every instance of `$` to `j` using the method I describe above.
Hopefully this helps! [Here is a working demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/ztYxs/)

Comment: Hi, and thanks for responding, I attempted to try out your method, and after implementing for some reason the chat box would no longer show messages. If you typed anything in though and hit submit it would load a new page echoing the  "success" function along with the text you entered ( all in { }'s ) of course.

I checked out the Error Console in Firefox though and I'm getting a
"TypeError: j is not a function"    and it keeps repeating this every second on the error list.

I checked the line it was referring to `code
j('#daddy-shoutbox-list').prepend(prepare(json[i]));`

Comment: after looking over the script again I noticed that at one point j is called as a variable to another function. So I changed "j" to "m" and now chat loads up. The only issue now is when I hit submit, nothing happens just the load bar sits there.

If I hit refresh though the new response is there. Any suggestions for where I should look to see why its unable to fully process the refresh? Again I greatly appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Edit

I was able to capture this in the Error Console
`code Timestamp: 3/24/2013 11:31:37 AM
Error: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[@name=message]
Source File: /application/modules/Photoviewer/externals/scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js?c=81
Line: 2 `

Would this mean that the variable I declared is now messing with another script? If so sounds like I"m on a roll at least.

edit, changing the variable still produced the same error. Looking at the referring script to see whats being called.

Comment: So far the only issue I see is that when the refresh/screen update function or whatever it is is called to update everything, thats when the new msg's appear in the shoutbox. 

Question is how do I seperate these 2 as they're both performing the same action?

Comment: Do you have an URL that can be seen?

Comment: yes it requires a login though if you could email me I can provide the info and login.    Dekikun@gmail.com

Comment: I don't mind paying for help on this as I'd really love to get this working. Please let me know when you would be available to look.